# AWS Pinpoint DAU Count

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-pinpoint

All configurations are made in the code and in the AWS Cognito and Pinpoint including Amplify,got the success message from the code , connected with AWS Cognito and Pinpoint also , able to get the user login data on AWS Cognito user pool but not on pinpoint analytics dashboard.

Tried configuring the code and settings in AWS but still facing the same issue .